# Heroku fails to host my Node.js App , I just see "Cannot Get /"

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have looked at similar questions and not been able to solve this problem with what I found. I initially followed a YouTube tutorial on how to deploy a Node.js App to Heroku. After trying and failing, I began troubleshooting and could not fix the problem.

I then followed the instructions on Heroku's website for deploying a Node.js application here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs and I found I seem to have done all the steps correctly. I was just missing the node version in the package.json which I have now added.

Here is how I have connected my Node.js app:
[image of Heroku application dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyUt7.png)

And here is the connected Github repo: https://github.com/AmeenIzhac/food-and-flow-backend

You can see in the repo that my port is specified correctly:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
```

I then tried running the app locally on the command line with:

```
heroku local web
```

and this worked as you can see my application running on port 5000:

[App running locally on port 5000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1RJQ.png)

However when I press "Open app" in Heroku, I just see this:

[Heroku hosted app fails to get /](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMMNM.png)

I feel like I have done everything correctly but it doesn't seem to work. Any help to get it working would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need a procfile. What is the heroku error in heroku logs --tail?

Comment: It also should work as long as I provide a start script in package.json which I do. Heroku docs: "To determine how to start your app, Heroku first looks for a Procfile. If no Procfile exists for a Node.js app, we will attempt to start a default web process via the start script in your package.json."

Comment: Heres what I see in the logs: 
2022-08-17T14:54:59.293482+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=food-and-flow-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=1dd11a09-53bc-4748-a419-d965761ecc94 fwd="51.199.177.63" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=383 protocol=https
2022-08-17T15:31:07.412723+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2022-08-17T15:31:07.415212+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2022-08-17T15:31:08.123115+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-08-17T15:31:09.163779+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143

Comment: Maybe you've run out of time on your free dynos https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#free-dyno-hour-pool

Comment: I checked now, I still have 546 hours left :/